# Preserving comments in Turtle RDF file (RDFlib)

Tags: python, rdf, rdflib, turtle-rdf

I would like to preserve the comments, these comments are defined using the hash sign (#)  within the Turtle RDF file I am updating with the Python RDFLib library.

My RDF file looks like this

```
# geospatial prefix
@prefix geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#> .
@prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix prov: <http://www.w3.org/ns/prov#> .

<#TestTripleMap>
    rr:logicalTable [
        rr:tableName "TEST" ;
    ] ;

    # subject map
    rr:subjectMap [
                  # of type geo:Geometry
        rr:class geo:Geometry ;
    ] ;

    rr:predicateObjectMap [
                          # attributed to data source
        rr:predicate prov:attributeTo ;
        rr:objectMap [
            rr:column "DATA_SOURCE" ;
        ] ;
    ] ;
.
```

And my code like this

```
g = Graph().parse(mapping_file, format="ttl")
# just an example triple 
g.add((bob, FOAF.age, Literal(42)))
print(g.serialize(format="ttl").decode("utf-8"))
```

But the output doesn't contain the comments in the original file......Any advice would be greatly appreciated!-

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I mean, comments can occur anywhere in the Turtle document, but when you parse the Turtle document into a set of RDF triples, it which point do you want to keep track of the comments? They do not have any logical meaning for RDF nor is there any logical reference to a particular RDF triple, so I don't see how any API would handle this. Also, there is no ordering when serializing RDF triples, so the comments would be meaningless if the other triples or somewhere else.

Comment: I was thinking the same  but hoping there was some work around, the users add the comments to their RDF and not me so Its not ideal.....

Comment: Just confirming: indeed there is no handling of comments in RDFlib through a serialize/deserialize cycle.

Some vendors require comments in Turtle files (e.g. TopQuadrant's platform that needs baseURI declarations) and these are always hard to handle in RDFlib, however remember that file top comments can just be added back in using standard Python. Remember: you always have all of Python to use alongside RDFlib!

Answer (score 2):

Just confirming: indeed there is no handling of comments in RDFlib through a serialize/deserialize cycle.

Answer (score 0):

add a blank node with annotation

_bx: rdfs:annotation """ long text """ .